# How to conditionally exit SQL Plus from PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

I have a main SQL script (say `main.sql`) which includes other files like so:

```
-- Contents of main.sql 
@@init.sql
@@body.sql
```

This template is fixed and I have no control over it. I can only put any code into the included files. `Init.sql` consists of PL/SQL code. `Main.sql` is run using SQL Plus. Now I want the following behavior of `init.sql`:

1. if `cond1` is true then `init.sql` should terminate the execution of `main.sql` with an error such that `body.sql` doesn't run
2. if `cond2` is true then `init.sql` should terminate the execution of `main.sql` with success such that `body.sql` doesn't run either
3. if `cond3` is true then `init.sql` should successfully exit and the execution of `body.sql` should start

I am trying to get this behaviour using `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` together with `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT` as I've learned that this is the only way of terminating an execution in SQL Plus completely, but I have troubles in achieving the bullet No.2 as

- I can't make `init.sql` exit to the operating system with 0 code. I've tried to set a bind variable and use `WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT :retcode` but `:retcode` appears to be empty when `EXIT` is called even if  `dbms_output.put_line` outputs the correct value of this variable immediately before calling `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`
- This situation is normal and I'd rather not have an Oracle exception appearing

Could you help me to accomplish the bullet No.2 or maybe suggest a totally different approach overall.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle different return codes by conditionally calling one or another sql file containing the return code you like:

*cond1.sql*:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
```

*cond2.sql*:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 0
```

Then here is how your `init.sql` starts:

```
--> Variable for init condition
col the_cond New_value the_cond noprint

--> select into condition variable
Select decode(smthg, 1, 'cond1', 2, 'cond2') the_cond 
  From table Where (whatever);

-- call to the host for the file:
@/path/to/the_file/&the_cond

begin
  -- then here an exception will cause exit, with return code set right before in file the_cond
end;
/
```

Not very satisfying, but hopping it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

init.sql:

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 0
BEGIN
  IF COND2 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Cant continue');
  END IF;
END;
/
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1    
BEGIN
  IF COND1 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Cant continue');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: Are you sure this solution allows to switch *`sqlplus`* return codes? What I understood is OP wanted: `condition 1`=> exit + return code=1; `condition 2`=> exit + return code=0.

Comment: @J. Chomel, you're right, I had misunderstood the question.